# Easy selenium selecting?

Tags: selenium

Does anyone have any resources on usage of selenium selectors (specifically javascript)

Ideally there'd be a chrome plugin that allows you to inspect an element and gives you the (all) method(s) of selecting it.

The IDE for firefox looks nice: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Just wondering if there are's anyway to simplify this annoying task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (but highly discouraged) use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) to generate CSS selectors/XPaths.

For complex web applications, there is no way you can get maintainable locators from those generators.

Auto-generated selectors are purely rubbish in terms of maintenance. Machines can't determine what is the most efficient way to locate, unless developers construct some certain algorithms depending on the structure of DOM. But I believe that is much hard than learning XPath or CSS selector.

My suggestion would be every Selenium developers should learn XPath and CSS selectors properly. Firebug + Firepath would be a good tool to evaluate and validate the locators, but please compose them from scratch.

For example, this is what a basic XPath generator would give you:

```
.//*[@id='page']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a
```

This is what a "smart" generator might do (which simplifies XPath by certain pre-defined rules, but may still cause trouble):

```
.//*[@id='page']//a
```

But this what a experienced human developer would do:

```
.//*[@id='page']//div[starts-with(@class, 'header-')]//a[contains(@class, '/blog')]
```

Comment: Good to know! I guess it's similar to why WYSIWIGS haven't become widespread for "real" use yet, the output quality isn't high enough to allow usage with other things.